Analog sensor isolation for Raspberry Pico analog pins
I’m designing a logger to collect data from a thermocouple (may be any type) using Raspberry Pico (3.3V). I want to isolate analog pins. As per my study inductive isolation can be done to transfer power proportional to the input analog signal.
Suggest a reliable way of isolation and ICs as per my requirement. Please mention if there is any alternative of inductive isolation to transfer signal proportional to input.

Analog isolation is very complicated.
It is much easier to use a thermocouple-to-digital IC with an easy to isolate interface like SPI. Here's an example.
The IC offers useful features like high accuracy ADC and cold junction compensation.
All SPI signals are unidirectional, so to isolate it, you only need three cheap digital optocouplers and an isolated power supply. I2C would be more complicated as the data line is bidirectional.
